# Textbox on a Combobox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

```
<Grid>
    <ComboBox Name="comboBox1" />
    <TextBox Name="TextBox1" />
</Grid>
```

In my wpf application I want to display a textbox on a combobox but i don't know how to maintain textbox size so that it only covers the box part of the combobox and not the down arrow part of combobox?

[image: like this]

Comment: Use a custom ControlTemplate.

Comment: Wouldn't it help to just make the combobox editable and skip the textbox completely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like:

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="119*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="17" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="134" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
        <TextBox Name="textBox1" Margin="0,0,0,3" />
    </Grid>
```

The key thing is to set the grid's second column to a fixed size, where that fixed sized represents the visibility of the arrow.

though, like others have mentioned, the best thing to do is set the combobox's IsEditable property to true:

```
<ComboBox Name="combobox1" LostFocus="LostFocus" IsEditable="True"/>
```

for more info, see here: [WPF ComboBox - IsEditable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox.iseditable.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a good reason to place a textbox over a combobox, as combobox itself is editable.

But what you can do is, divide your combobox in two gridcolums with later column being fixed sized includeing the arrow part of combobox and former column being star sized. Let combobox have columnspan of 2 and textbox of 1.

hope it helps